# How to use input to find a text file in a console app

Tags: c#

Hello Friends I'm back with another question! This time it's actually pretty basic. I'm learning how to use text files at the moment and I'm trying to use user input to complete a streamreader argument. The problem I have is that when the program does find that a text file exists, it does not print its contents to the console. Could someone help me with this? The output does not show anything and it continues to infinity not printing. I.E. its just scrolling down.

here's what I have so far.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello! This application lets you write application entries!");
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The text File: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Nate\\Desktop\\TextFiles\\" + input);
            using (reader)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (reader != null)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That file does not exist!");
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory does not exist!");
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oops! Something Wrong happened!");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: changes are its just sitting at your readkey - because you've only allowed for 3 possible issues. If you add a catch (Exception e) you could print the error and find out what your error is

Comment: Step through your code. Perhaps there isn't any data in the file? Walk through your process of reading from the file, and see what it gets. Check the other properties of your object to see if perhaps you're doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Check out http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader

Comment: Does the file contain any text when you open it notepad or something similar? Your code is fine (though it should be `while (line != null)` rather than `reader != null`), and it's obviously outputing (it's the `WriteLine`s that are doing the "scrolling"). And off-topic here, but since you're learning from scratch, you might want to use current best practices / styles (e.g. `var`, `using (var reader = ...)`, `while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)` or even better, `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(...)`). These change all the time, of course :P

Comment: @Luaan Your small change actually saved my code! changing it to while(line!= null) made it work like i wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change the following:**

```
while (reader != null)
```

To:

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream )
```

In that way you are reading from the file until its end.

**ReadLine need to be inside the loop:**

```
 while (!reader.EndOfStream )
 {
      string line = reader.ReadLine();
      // .... 
 }
```

**For readibility purpose, you can change this:**

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Nate\\Desktop\\TextFiles\\" + input);
using (reader)
{
    //...
}
```

To:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Nate\Desktop\TextFiles\" + input))
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I was able to mend my small bug! It's amazing how fast people on this site are to respond. Loving the community we have here. <3

Answer (score 0):

Your try block should be as follows;

```
try
{
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Nate\Desktop\TextFiles\" + input);
   using (reader)
   {
       while (!reader.EndOfStream)
       {
           var line = reader.ReadLine();
           Console.WriteLine(line);
       }
   }
}
```